# Django | sort one-to-many relationship on Master's admin page

Tags: jquery, django, django-models, django-admin

I have two models:

```
Folder
  ...

Photo
  folder = models.ForeignKey(Folder)
```

I was wondering if I can add a field to **Folder**'s Admin edit page so that I can order the list of photos that would relate to that folder.

Comment: Any reason why you wouldn't put the order field in the photo / inline? You could normalize a textfield or something with key value pairs of photo IDs to their order value... but it seems much more natural to put a per-photo attribute on the per-photo table you already have.

Comment: I do have the order field on the photo itself, but I want to let the user edit the order of the photos per folder. It'll be tough to know what the order is if they're not all in the same scope (the folder) when editing.

Comment: Ohh, I see what you're saying now. A per-folder-photo ordering. But still, if a photo can only ever have one folder, isn't the ordering for that photo only ever related to one folder?

Comment: Ya, but lets say there are forty folders and 1000 photos. Editing the order number of each photo on the photo's own edit page won't really be the easiest thing to manage properly.

Comment: Ohh, I see. Somehow I didn't understand your question correctly. I will add an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `InlineModelAdmin` and development version of django, you can set `ordering` option and have the photos ordered.

Check the docs: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-options

Comment: That's pretty sick. I'm guessing I can override what shows up in the photo fields, and then use list_editable somehow to work in some jQuery to sort them in place?

Comment: I haven't yet tried `jQuery` in `Django Admin`. I know it's there, but I try to use only documented options and usually that's enough.

Comment: Do you think there's a way to do what I'm talking about with the builtin in stuff?

Comment: I just realized that you answered the question exactly how I asked it... I guess I just have to figure out how to customize the inline part.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a common problem with a not so documented fix that I found while trying to solve the same problem.

Specify the `FormSet` used by the `Inline` and override `get_queryset()` in your formset definition.

```
from django.forms.models import BaseInlineFormSet

class OrderedFormSet(BaseInlineFormSet):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(OrderedFormset, self).get_queryset().order_by('-sortfield')

class MyInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Item
    formset = OrderedFormSet
```

Comment: Yuji, what's the difference between using the formset to order the items and using the ordering like in gruszczy's answer?

Comment: `ordering` inlines doesn't exist on the latest release. It's in the development version only.

Comment: ah. got ya... so the development version 'ordering' field actually takes care of this exact situation...